# AutoDeploy rails app via jenkins and capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, amazon-ec2, capistrano3

As first steps I have configured AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu 16.04 and configured Capistrano for deploy from local to this AWS EC2 instance.

Now I am trying to make autodeploy rails app from GitHub to this Ubuntu Server (AWS EC2) via Jenkins and Capistrano. Note: I am creating autodeploy for the first time.

My rails app (production) and Jenkins are on the same Amazon EC2 instance.
When Jenkins task starts, it clones repo to the jenkins workspace, install gems and then execute: cap production deploy

But now I can“t check that the Capistrano was configured correctly for deploy to another folder of the same server, because when `cap production deploy` executes I get this error:

`Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user jenkins@`

I tried to create ssh-key for user jenkins and add it to ubuntu user (default non-root sudo user) by:
`ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id ubuntu@127.0.0.1` 
and always get permission denied error.

Does anybody have any suggestions?
Thank you in advance
capistrano version 3.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `jenkin` user's `public-key` in the `authorized_keys` file of `ubuntu` user. You can find it at `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

However, In my opinion, you should migrate the `jenkins` runner to a separate server.

You can create a VPC group, and put both the servers, production and jenkins runner in that single VPC, and expose `ssh` port in the same VPC, so that no one outside can access it.

Then add the public key of the`jenkins` server to the production server as I have explained above.